# Using control state with standard controls

Tags: asp.net

Can we use ControlState with one of the standard ASP .Net controls like TextBox etc.? and how?
The examples which I always find regarding this is for custom controls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ControlState` and `ViewState` both can be used in CustomControl, but only `ViewState` can be used in normal web form controls.